# Use Azure "Run Command" to add my SSH keys to the ones authorized

Tags: azure, ssh, azure-virtual-machine

So I have a Azure VM I lost the SSH key to. I'm trying to evaluate my options - seems like the most obvious one would be to regenerate them using the portal (I have full access there).

Now I made some tests using the "Run Command" option, and I'm wondering: what would prevent me to use that to add my own SSH key to the authorized_keys file (that I manage to see/echo using cat)?

It feels bad to me (that would be defacto a way to get past SSH keys), but on the other hand if I have that access, I can reset them anyway so maybe that's not much of an issue?

I tried to find back the key (.pem), but could not. I tried to use "ls/cat" in the Run Command but the key does not seems to be stored on the .ssh folder on the remote VM.

Answer (score 0):

> Now I made some tests using the "Run Command" option, and I'm wondering: what would prevent me to use that to add my own SSH key to the authorized_keys file (that I manage to see/echo using cat)?

Adding your own SSH key to the authorized_keys file using the `Run Command` option is not a recommended. It is a security risk and could potentially compromise the security of your VM it could potentially allow unauthorized access to your VM.

In order to authenticate to the vm with SSH key even you lost the existing key follow the below steps to authenticate the vm:

Created ssh keygen using `ssh-keygen -t rsa -m PEM -b 4096`

```c
ssh-keygen -t rsa -m PEM -b 4096 
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/home/azureuser/.ssh/id_rsa):
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
Enter same passphrase again:
Your identification has been saved in /home/azureuser/.ssh/id_rsa.
Your public key has been saved in /home/azureuser/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
SHA256:vFfHHrpSGQBd/oNdvNiX0sG9Vh+wROlZBktNZw9AUjA azureuser@myserver
The key's randomart image is:
+---[RSA 4096]----+
|        .oE=*B*+ |
|          o+o.*++|
|           .oo++*|
|       .    .B+.O|
|        S   o=BO.|
|         . .o++o |
|        . ... .  |
|         ..  .   |
|           ..    |
+----[SHA256]-----+
```

Then, use `code id_rsa .pub` copy the public key and reset the password in portal like below:

[image]

[image]

Now use `code id_rsa` you can see private key ***copy the private key paste in the existing `.pem` file*** and use the file path to login SSH for .pem file you can make use of [putty](https://youtu.be/sBV6SJK35JE) or you can download manually.

[image]

This way you use your past .`pem`. Now when I try to login with.`pem` file SSH connected successfully like below:

[image: https://i.imgur.com/gUDyyaX.png]

[image: [Output](https://i.imgur.com/vphd9bD.png)]

```
C:\Users\khan> ssh -i "<Copy the file payh of .pem file>" azureuser@172.174.56.11
Welcome to Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.15.0-1041-azure x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage

  System information as of Tue Jul 11 10:56:31 UTC 2023

  System load:  0.06689453125     Processes:             106
  Usage of /:   7.9% of 28.89GB   Users logged in:       0
  Memory usage: 58%               IPv4 address for eth0: 10.1.0.4
  Swap usage:   0%

 * Strictly confined Kubernetes makes edge and IoT secure. Learn how MicroK8s
   just raised the bar for easy, resilient and secure K8s cluster deployment.

   https://ubuntu.com/engage/secure-kubernetes-at-the-edge
```